# Getting Assembly could not load error in .Net 5.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, .net-5

I have created console application in .NET 5.0 framework and trying to load package using Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS but I am getting error 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

**Code :**

```
            Package package =null;
            Application app = new Application();
            try
            {

                string package_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DTSPackageImport"];
                package = app.LoadPackage(@package_path, null);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                package.Dispose();
                package = null;
            }
```

**StackTrace:**

```
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents100 events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\..\Sample Demo\consolDotNet5\consoldotnet5\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 18
```

**ManagedDTS version:**
Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0

Please help me out of this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste the string that you specified in the AppSettings "`packageName`". And is your console using 64bit?

Comment: The wrong version of the library is added is in your proj file.  Easiest way of fixing these errors is in Solution Explorer delete the current version of library under references.  Then add a new reference which will add the correct version of the library to the proj file.  Then do a clean build which will emove the obj file used with the old library.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
 - install the SDK tools, if not installed
 - go to properties of the project and check in debug configuration-> if the 64-bit is true set it to false and vice versa
```

if these do not help, then you will need to provide extra information.